# Position Dialog in primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Shortly: i want to position a dialog in the middle of the screen and not in the middle of the page.

I have a problem positioning a dialog with primefaces. My Dialog is usualy in the middle of the screen and if the height of my page is not bigger than my screen its ok. But if there is a scroll bar and the height is for example 3 times my screen (e.g. 3072 in a 1280*1024 resolution), the Dialog is displayed at position 1536, which is out of my screen. As the background is frozen, the only way i can do something is by refreshing or leaving the page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute `position`:

`position="center"`

Other possible values are:

1. top
2. bottom
3. left
4. right
5. right,top
6. right,bottom
7. left,top
8. left,bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use html .

1. -Create div element.Firstly hide it
2. When you want to show it,change z-index and display of div element.
3. -You can use size that you want

My idea :)